Adding SVG to PDF using jsPDF on server (using NestJS or NodeJS)
I am trying to insert a SVG to my PDF using NestJS and jsPDF. But I think jsPDF doens't have support for inserting SVGs on server. Is there any way around this someone has found? Would be really helpful.
I have made a addImage function that is working as expected and inserting the image:
  addImage = (imageData: Buffer, options?: any): void => {
    this.doc.addImage(
      imageData,
      'JPEG',
      options?.x || this.x,
      options?.y || this.y,
      options?.width || this.doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth(),
      options?.height || this.doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight(),
    );

    this.y =
      options?.height ||
      this.doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight() + this.doc.getLineHeight();
    this.updatePointer();
  };

But the addSvgAsImage (as per the jsPDF docs jsPDF Docs: SVG) function doesn't seem to work

What's in your SVG because addSvgAsImage says it only supports paths per the documentation you linked in your question.

This issue has been resolved in jsPDF already if your dont find your answer yet check the link below
How to add SVG to PDF
